# React render HTML from parent component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I run into an issue in the rendering. I did some search online, but I didn't find a solution.

In the parent component:

```
<Child prop1={this.getHeader()}>

getHeader() : function () {
  return (<div> Header </div>)
}
```

In the Child component:

```
render() : function () {
  return (<div> {this.props.prop1} </div>)
}
```

However, the div didn't get rendered. I checked other solution and tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML, but it will render the string of " Header " rather than the element. Could i get some help?

Comment: Those code snippets are invalid ReactJs, also, your render function is returning another function instead of just JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working solution:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  getHeader() {
    return <div> Header </div>;
  }

  render() {
    return <Child prop1={this.getHeader()} />;
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div> {this.props.prop1} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5m29cw1/6/

Comment: Thanks. May I know why it works? I still don't understand what's the problem I have.

Comment: This makes no sense: `getHeader() : function () {...}`. I changed how you declare functions and that's pretty much it. Please, mark the answer as accept if you find it helpful.